# LESS does not compile like it should, gives "is undefined" error

Tags: javascript, html, css, compiler-errors, less

I have a `desktop.less` file where all the LESS files are imported and then the `desktop.less` files gets compiled. This works fine. But today I made a `mixins.less` file. And in that file I have one mixin for setting the height of a few elements:
`(mixins.less)`

```
// Set height of the form
.form-height(@height: 43px;) {
   .sd-select {
      height: @height;
   }
  .form-control {
      height: @height;
  }
}
```

And then I put the `.form-height` in another LESS file like this:
`(new-landing.less)`

```
.standard-form {
   .form-height;
    &.registerLandingForm {
       width: 926px;
    }
   .sd-select {
       &:before {

       }
   }
}
```

But when I compile I get `.form-height is undefined`

What is causing this? I tried to put the `mixins.less` file first in the `desktop.less` but it is still giving me that error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you import the `mixins.less` file? `@import 'mixins.less'`

Comment: @Simplicity Yes, just like that

Comment: Is it in a different folder than the `new-landing.less` ?

Comment: @Simplicity Yes, but new-landing.less and mixins.less are imported in desktop.less, and desktop.less gets compiled

Comment: Is the path correct? i.e. `@import 'mixins/mixins.less'`?

Comment: @Simplicity Yes, I don't understand why it is giving me a error. I will make a  screenshot of it

Comment: @Simplicity Here is the screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/mhAo4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122746/discussion-between-simplicity-and-bristov).

Comment: Looks like we're missing a little information. Can you add the relevant part of `desktop.less`, and write out where the different less files are in the folder structure? And what tool/app/etc are you using to compile?